# angularjs second http call unsuccessful

Tags: angularjs

I have a function which is called on controller load (PlanCtrl corresponding to tab-plan.html where accordion list is populated, *see bellow*):

```
$scope.initialize = function() {

  if ($cookies.token) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token ' + $cookies.token;
  }

  var url = "https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/exercises/get_exercise/";
  var memory_url = "https://127.0.0.1:8000/api2/games/get_game/";

  $http({
    url: memory_url,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRFToken': $cookies['csrftoken'],
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
  })

  .success(function(response) {
    alert("suc 1")
    $scope.initial_data_memory = response;
    console.log($scope.initial_data_memory);

    angular.forEach($scope.initial_data_memory, function(item) {

      $scope.game_type = item.game_type;

      //check the exercise date  
      $scope.current_date_memory = item.current_date;


      $scope.days = Plan.all();
      //Iterate over the list
      angular.forEach($scope.days, function(value1, key) {

        //iterate over the list of exercises
        angular.forEach(value1.exercises, function(value2, key) {

          // Check if the fetched exercise id is same as current exercise from the frontend list and check if the fetched date is today 
          if (value2.id == $scope.game_type && $scope.today === $scope.current_date_memory) {
            // If the fetched date is todat i.e. exercise was rated today: set the flag for watchedTodat to true 
            value2.watchedToday = true;

          }

        });

      });

    });
  });

  $http({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRFToken': $cookies['csrftoken'],
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
  })

  .success(function(response) {
    alert("suc 2")
    $scope.initial_data = response;
    console.log($scope.initial_data);

    angular.forEach($scope.initial_data, function(item) {

      $scope.exercise_type = item.exercise_type;

      //check the exercise date  
      $scope.current_date = item.current_date;


      $scope.days = Plan.all();
      //Iterate over the list
      angular.forEach($scope.days, function(value1, key) {

        //iterate over the list of exercises
        angular.forEach(value1.exercises, function(value2, key) {
          // Check if the fetched exercise id is same as current exercise from the frontend list and check if the fetched date is today 
          if (value2.id == $scope.exercise_type && $scope.today === $scope.current_date) {
            // If the fetched date is today i.e. exercise was rated today: set the flag for watchedTodat to true 
            value2.watchedToday = true;

          }

        });

      });

    });
  });

};
```

It has two http calls (order do not matter), when the controller loads for the first time only first call is executed, when it loads for the second time, then the second http call is executed/is successful.

**Why does it happen?**

**UPDATE:**
I put alerts in both success parts: both HTTP calls are made, however the last statement `value2.watchedToday = true;` which sets a boolean value to enable a checkmark, sets only for second http call. See image bellow (ideally there should be checkmarks agains Best Stretch and Buttterfly reverse):

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<ion-list>
  <div ng-repeat="day in days"><br>
    <div class="item item-icon-left"  ng-click="toggleGroup(day)" ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(day)}">
      <i class="icon icon-accessory" ng-class="isGroupShown(day) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
      &nbsp;
      {{day.name}}
    </div>
    <a class="item item-icon-left item-accordion" ng-show="isGroupShown(day)" ng-repeat="exercise in day.exercises" type="item-text-wrap"
       href="#/tab/plan/{{exercise.id}}">
      {{exercise.name}}

      <!-- Trial LED -->

        <span style="float:right;"><i ng-show="{{exercise.watchedToday}}==true" class="ion-checkmark-round"></i></span>

    </a>
  </div>
</ion-list>
```

**Routes:**

```
.state('tab.plan', {
    url: '/plan',
    resolve: {
      authenticated: ['djangoAuth', function(djangoAuth){
        return djangoAuth.authenticationStatus();
      }],
    },
    views: {
      'tab-plan': {
        templateUrl: '/templates/tab-plan.html',
        controller: 'planCtrl'
      }
    },
    cache: false
  })

  .state('tab.simon', {
    url: '/plan/8', 
    resolve: {
      authenticated: ['djangoAuth', function(djangoAuth){
        return djangoAuth.authenticationStatus();
      }],
    },
    views: {
      'tab-plan': {
        templateUrl: '/templates/simon.html',
        controller: 'simonCtrl',
        data: {
          css: '/css/simon.css'
        }  
      }
    },
    cache: false
  })
...
.state('tab.exercise', {
    url: '/plan/:exerciseId', 
    resolve: {
      authenticated: ['djangoAuth', function(djangoAuth){
        return djangoAuth.authenticationStatus();
      }],
    },
    views: {
      'tab-plan': {
        templateUrl: '/templates/video.html',
        controller: 'videoCtrl'
      }
    },
    cache: false
  })
```

Best Stretch, Butterfly, Squat, Plank, Push up, Side plank share common controller (videoCtrl + video.html) and all others have their own controllers and templates.

Comment: Perhaps you should implement error handlers? Does token exist first time? Not much detail given

Comment: image doesn't show how that html is generated. Neither does it show us the data used. You are also using `$scope` for local variables inside your loops which makes no sense

Comment: Are the calls related to each other? Do they require an order? If so, try to do the second query inside the success function of the first (or the other way around)